# How do you calculate variables in vector addition?

Tags: vectors

I'm currently completing Specialist Maths Unit 1, Topic 2 "Vectors in the plane", and I've come across a question I can't solve.

Four vectors are given. The first two of these vectors, when added, lead to the same point as the last two vectors when added. However, the magnitude of one of the first two vectors isn't given, and the magnitude of one of the last two vectors isn't given.

The first two vectors are (10.5, $\angle225^\text{o}$) and ($\alpha, \angle315^\text{o}$).

The last two vectors are (14, $\angle330^\text{o}$) and ($\beta, \angle240^\text{o}$).

I tried converting them to Cartesian form:

a = |a|cos(θ)î + |a|sin(θ)ĵ
a = 10.5 × cos(225°)î + 10.5 × sin(225°)ĵ
a = –7.42î – 7.42ĵ (2 d. p.)
b = |α|cos(θ)î + |α|sin(θ)ĵ
b = α × cos(315°)î + α × sin(315°)ĵ
b = 0.71αî – 0.71αĵ (2 d. p.)
c = |c|cos(θ)î + |c|sin(θ)ĵ
c = 14 × cos(330°)î + 14 × sin(330°)ĵ
c = 12.12î – 7ĵ (2 d. p.)
d = |d|cos(θ)î + |d|sin(θ)ĵ
d = β × cos(240°)î + β × sin(240°)ĵ
d = –0.5βî – 0.87βĵ (2 d. p.)

And using substitution to calculate α and β:

–7.42î – 7.42ĵ + 0.71αî – 0.71αĵ = 12.12î – 7ĵ – 0.5βî – 0.87βĵ
–7.42î + 0.71αî = 12.12î – 0.5βî
0.71α = 12.12 – 0.5β + 7.42
0.71α = 19.54 – 0.5β
α = (19.54 – 0.5β) / 0.71

12.12î – 0.5βî = –7.42î + 0.71αî
12.12î – 0.5βî = –7.42î + 0.71((19.54 – 0.5)/0.71)î
12.12 – 0.5β = –7.42 + 19.54 – 0.5β
–0.5β = –7.42 + 19.54 – 0.5β
–0.5β = 12.12 – 0.5β
β = (12.12 – 0.5β)/–0.5
β = 24.24 + β
2β = 24.24
β = 24.24/2
β = 12.12

–7.42î + 0.71αî = 12.12î – 0.5βî
–7.42 + 0.71α = 12.12 – 0.5(12.12)
–7.42 + 0.71α = 12.12 – 0.5(12.12)
–7.42 + 0.71α = 12.12 – 6.06
0.71α = 12.12 – 6.06 + 7.42
0.71α = 13.48
α = 13.48/0.71
α = 18.99

I then tried to solve the vectors using the discovered variables.

–7.42î – 7.42ĵ + 0.71αî – 0.71αĵ = 12.12î – 7ĵ – 0.5βî – 0.87βĵ
–7.42î – 7.42ĵ + 0.71(18.99)î – 0.71(18.99)ĵ = 12.12î – 7ĵ – 0.5(12.12)î – 0.87(12.12)ĵ
–7.42î – 7.42ĵ + 13.48î – 13.48ĵ = 12.12î – 7ĵ – 6.06î – 10.5ĵ
(–7.42 + 13.48)î + (–7.42 – 13.48)ĵ = (12.12 – 6.06)î + (–7 – 10.5)ĵ
6.06î – 20.9ĵ ≠ 6.06î – 17.5ĵ

As you can see, the result is incorrect.

Is this the correct method for solving this problem and I simply made a mistake in the process? Or should a different method be used for determining an answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two linear simultaneous equations to solve:

$$10 \sin(225^\circ)+\alpha \sin(315^\circ) = 14 \sin(330^\circ) + \beta \sin(240^\circ)$$
$$10 \cos(225^\circ)+\alpha \cos(315^\circ) = 14 \cos(330^\circ) + \beta \cos(240^\circ)$$

which we can write (multiplying by $- 2$) as

$$10 \sqrt2+\alpha \sqrt{2} = 14 + \beta \sqrt{3}$$
$$10 \sqrt2-\alpha \sqrt{2} = -14 \sqrt{3} + \beta$$

so $\beta = 10 \sqrt2-\alpha \sqrt{2} +14 \sqrt{3}$ and thus

$$\alpha =\frac{ 56 + 10 \sqrt6 -10 \sqrt2}{\sqrt6 + \sqrt2}\approx 17.173 $$
$$\beta =\frac{ 40 + 14 \sqrt6 -14 \sqrt2}{\sqrt6 + \sqrt2} \approx 14.104$$

Comment: @depressed_student Perhaps you were supposed to draw it on a piece of paper (the two vectors you know and the two directions where you do not know the lengths, see where the lines cross, and then measure the lengths.

Comment: I think you're right. I used a graphing program though, Geogebra. Thank you!